# How to change the ID number of the SCSI bus

Tags: ssd, raid1, scsi

I've 2 disk in RAID1 which is broken. I worked several day thinking the RAID is working and I noted not because several files is missing after a reboot. 
The odder the disk doesn't want to take its old number now so I unplugged the old version of my system and I checked that on the system I would like to keep:

```
cat /proc/scsi/scsi
Attached devices:
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: TSSTcorp Model: DVD-ROM SH-D163B Rev: SB01
  Type:   CD-ROM                           ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 01 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ASUS     Model: DRW-20B1LT       Rev: 1.00
  Type:   CD-ROM                           ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 01 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATA      Model: Samsung SSD 840  Rev: DXT0
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 0
```

I would like to how to change the ID of the Samsung SSD to 0 and boot every times on it for repair my RAID

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The ID numbers are just sequentially assigned from free devices. If something else is still use an ID, that ID would be skipped on reinsertion.

Why do you need the samsung 840 to be ID zero? Based on your output above, it should always appear as /dev/sda.

Comment: Hi @robbat2 For answering your question :  Because something passed wrong on my RAID1 and the disk has been desynchronized, occurred a disk with a pass version of my system, and a disk with  the actual version of system. Now if I plug my both disk I boot on the old version of my system. I've to let the old version of system unplugged off for get a normal boot.

Comment: boot the correct disk, then attach the old disk (while the system is online); set-faulty on the old RAID partitions, and then re-add.

If you don't feel comfortable doing the above while the system is on, boot the old drive on a livecd/usb, and mark it's raid faulty before you boot again.